# How to type a TypeScript method with a type alias?

Tags: typescript

How can I type a function (not arrow) method in TypeScript with a type alias?

With arrow functions, I can do:

```
type FooFn = () => boolean

class ClassA {
    public foo: FooFn = () => true;
}
```

And I need to do the same with:

```
class ClassB {
    public foo() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

How can this be done?

[demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nGA7KBeKAKAlGgfFAIwQBsIBDJAKEoGNiyBnBqAYXqYEEoBvSqfqGACuBYgEsaUAGYIAXLATI0mHKnzAATkIgBuSgF9qdRszYmAQjz4DhoidITYrAl1A0RgQjSk3a9Lw30gA)

Comment: maybe use `implements` ? See [here](https://tsplay.dev/wXQRVN)

Comment: There's no direct way to do this; a feature request that would enable this is at [ms/TS#22063](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22063).  See the answer to the linked question for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if this below is what you meant but you have to implement some sort of type to be able to do it.

Look below and see if this is what you meant

```ts
type FooFn = () => boolean

type FooExtender = {
    foo: FooFn;
}

class ClassA implements FooExtender {
    public foo: FooFn = () => true;
}

class ClassB implements FooExtender {
    public foo() {
        return true;
    }
}


console.log(new ClassB().foo())
```

Comment: I am looking for an alternative to `implements`, since it is more convenient in some cases.

Comment: there is no alternative